# python: how to normalize a data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I calculated RSI and used processing.normalize(RSI) to normalize my values in RSI.
However, the normalized values are just 1.
Can anyone help me to find why I get this error?

```
min(RSI_train.values)
Out[104]: array([ 11.3911171])

max(RSI_train.values)
Out[105]: array([ 83.9758361])

normalized_X = preprocessing.normalize(RSI_train)
normalized_X

Out[106]:
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       ..., 
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Comment: Show ```RSI_train.shape```. It should be ```(n_samples,nfeatures)```.

Comment: @sascha thanks for the comment. when I use RSI_train.shape, I get (3085,1). So I basically want to to linear scaling of the data within [-1.0 to 1.0]

Comment: Try ```preprocessing.normalize(RSI_train, axis=0)``` (default axis is 1, see [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn.preprocessing.normalize)). If you want scaling to -1,1, you should use MinMaxScaler though! -> ```preprocessing.minmax_scale(RSI_train, feature_range=(-1,1))``` (here axis=0 is default)

Comment: @sascha I think preprocessing.minmax_scale works! thank you!